# How to use result of previous calculated row based on a condition in sql?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table with two columns; MovingAverage and Baseline already populated. I want to add a calculated column that will be updated based on previous calculated value when a certain condition is met. I have looked at various posts regarding this but they don't seem to address what i need.

The condition is that:

```
if the current row moving average is >=1.13 * NewBaseline 
  then 1.15*Newbaseline 
  else Newbaseline
```

**Table:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need something like :

IF movingaverage >= (1.13 * NewBaseline)
       1.15*Newbaseline ;
ELSE 
       Newbaseline;

Tell me if it is something like that, that you are looking.

Comment: Newbaseline is calculated column, and for a given row  it needs to compare previous row of NewBaseline. e.g for  movaverage of rn 15 needs to be compared with NewBaseline value of rn 14

Answer (score 0):

#### This is the update recursive query for your scenario

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT m, MovAvg, BaseLine, BaseLine AS NewBaseline
      FROM MyTable
     WHERE m = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t1.m, t1.MovAvg, t1.BaseLine, 
           CAST(CASE WHEN t1.MovAvg >= 1.13 * t2.NewBaseline THEN 1.15 * t2.NewBaseline ELSE t2.NewBaseline END AS decimal(10,2)) AS NewBaseline
      FROM MyTable t1 INNER JOIN CTE t2 ON t1.m = t2.m + 1
)
UPDATE t1
   SET NewBaseline = t2.NewBaseline
  FROM MyTable t1 INNER JOIN CTE t2 ON t1.m = t2.m
```

Comment: I get the error message column m cannot be resolved.

Comment: I have changed to 
SELECT 1 as m, MovAvg, BaseLine, BaseLine AS NewBaseline
      FROM MyTable
will it give same output?

Comment: Also our implementation of presto does not support recursive CTE's. Do you suggest any other method?

Comment: any other comments on this?